# SQL Server: Copy Database Wizard: Execute SQL Server Agent Job Failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a database called ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST. I am trying to use the Copy wizard and make a duplicate database on this same SQL Server.

I am following the Tasks > Copy database wizard.

However, when it goes to copy, it always fails on the last step, Execute SQL Server Agent Job.

I am running this on the actual server that is running the SQL Server Service.

Any suggestions? The error log is not clear to me.

```
#Fields: event,computer,operator,source,sourceid,executionid,starttime,endtime,datacode,databytes,message
OnPreValidate,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,(null)
OnPreValidate,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,(null)
OnPostValidate,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,(null)
OnPostValidate,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,(null)
PackageStart,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Beginning of package execution.

Diagnostic,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Maximum concurrent executables are set to 1.

DiagnosticEx,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,<?xml version="1.0"?><DTS:ParameterValues xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"/>
OnPreExecute,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,(null)
OnPreExecute,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,(null)
OnPreValidate,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,(null)
OnPostValidate,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,(null)
OnProgress,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Task just started the execution.
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Connecting to server APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Connecting to server APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Connected to server APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Connected to server APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Connecting to server APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Connecting to server APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Connected to server APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Connected to server APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Transferring server objects to server APDNAPPSERV from APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Transferring server objects to server APDNAPPSERV from APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Transferring server objects to server APDNAPPSERV from APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:57 PM,0,0x,Transferring server objects to server APDNAPPSERV from APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,0,0x,Transferred server objects to APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,0,0x,Transferred server objects to APDNAPPSERV
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,0,0x,Transferring database ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST from APDNAPPSERV server as ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST_new to APDNAPPSERV server
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,0,0x,Transferring database ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST from APDNAPPSERV server as ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST_new to APDNAPPSERV server
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,0,0x,Added data file ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST in path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST_new.mdf to file group [PRIMARY]
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,0,0x,Added data file ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST in path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST_new.mdf to file group [PRIMARY]
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,0,0x,Added log file ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST_log in path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST_new_log.ldf
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,0,0x,Added log file ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST_log in path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST_new_log.ldf
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,0,0x,Transferring data to database ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST_new from ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST
OnInformation,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,5/16/2014 4:48:58 PM,0,0x,Transferring data to database ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST_new from ADNAS_TASK_USER_TEST
OnError,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:49:01 PM,5/16/2014 4:49:01 PM,0,0x,Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
StackTrace:    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExtendedProperty.ScriptDrop(StringCollection queries, ScriptingPreferences sp)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptDropObject(Urn urn, ScriptingPreferences sp, ObjectScriptingType& scriptType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptDrop(Urn urn, ScriptingPreferences sp, ObjectScriptingType& scriptType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptDropObjects(IEnumerable`1 urns)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptUrns(List`1 orderedUrns)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.DiscoverOrderScript(IEnumerable`1 urns)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptWorker(List`1 urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataTransferBase.GetScriptLoadedTransferWriter()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferDatabasesUsingSMOTransfer()
OnError,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:49:01 PM,5/16/2014 4:49:01 PM,0,0x,Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
StackTrace:    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExtendedProperty.ScriptDrop(StringCollection queries, ScriptingPreferences sp)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptDropObject(Urn urn, ScriptingPreferences sp, ObjectScriptingType& scriptType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptDrop(Urn urn, ScriptingPreferences sp, ObjectScriptingType& scriptType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptDropObjects(IEnumerable`1 urns)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptUrns(List`1 orderedUrns)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.DiscoverOrderScript(IEnumerable`1 urns)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptWorker(List`1 urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataTransferBase.GetScriptLoadedTransferWriter()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferDatabasesUsingSMOTransfer()
OnProgress,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,0,0x,Database transfer failed for 1 database(s).
OnProgress,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,100,0x,Transfer objects finished execution.
OnTaskFailed,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,0,0x,(null)
OnPostExecute,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_Transfer Objects Task,{080F54EA-739C-4C14-AD3E-75B10C0E6062},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,0,0x,(null)
OnWarning,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,-2147381246,0x,SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

OnPostExecute,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,0,0x,(null)
DiagnosticEx,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,0,0x,<?xml version="1.0"?><DTS:ProcessMemoryUsage xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"><DTS:PeakWorkingSetSize>85065728</DTS:PeakWorkingSetSize></DTS:ProcessMemoryUsage>
PackageEnd,APDNAPPSERV,NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT,CDW_APDNAPPSERV_APDNAPPSERV_5,{2E3BF5A7-43F6-4218-9F08-E36628ED4FC9},{8A06F1A2-C66D-4DED-84BA-98883AE35625},5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,5/16/2014 4:49:02 PM,1,0x,End of package execution.
```

Comment: Are you looping through an array?  It might be that the array is empty.  This line of your error log caught my attention "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

Answer (score 1):

I've found the copy wizard to be problematic.

I've found backup and then restoring to the new database to work much better and easier.  You will need to make sure and give new names for the mdf and log files though. Otherwise you run the risk of shared\overwriting log and mdf files (bad news).

Answer (score 0):

I selected `use the SQL Management Object Method` and it works, I was facing the same issue and now it is fixed with this `Select Transfer Method`.

Answer (score -1):

Some helpful information may be found here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274463

And here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx

Also, what is keeping you from making a backup and restoring it to the new database?